# I get this error when run the project in react native

Tags: react-native

implement exnavigation library into my project and then after i run the project i get this error please help me
 undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NavigationExperimental.Header')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react is innovating day by day and making built in functions and components so that it is easy for us to use and deliver great solutions.

I also faced same issue, but I moved http://reactnavigation.org. They have docs also to help us implement the navigation. I have got quite experience implementing the react navigation. If you have nay doubt. Feel free to ask me, I would love to help you out.

You can go through - https://hackernoon.com/getting-started-with-react-navigation-the-navigation-solution-for-react-native-ea3f4bd786a4 it is quite helpful.

Comment: I have tested on IOS, but it should work fine on Android. If you want I will be able to tell you by Monday 12 PM (IST). As in the https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/ they have shown in both. And react native is about coding platform. My recommendation would be to proceed with react navigation as this is recent add on by react team and they will enhance this much more

Answer (score 0):

From the `README` of ex-navigation:

> ExNavigation is built on top of NavigationExperimental

In the latest version of React Native they have already removed `NavigationExperimental`. So you *cannot* use `ex-navigation` with latest React Native.

Nowadays there are other navigation options like [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) or [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation)

Comment: You can use it just update it to the latest version and make sure you name the package @expo/ex-navigation. Works fine we use it.